# Mirroring value from one input to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have found a few posts here relating to this, but they all work only one way, such as:

```
$("#a").on("change",function() { $(".aa").val($(this).val()); });
```

But I need to figure out how to change EITHER of the inputs when one of them is updated. Currently my two fields look like so, using the above code works just fine from the first to second, but I need the first one to also update if someone changed the second input. I have multiple fields that need this applied, so I don't really want to just reverse the functions.

```
<input type="text" id="a" class="aa required standard" placeholder="0"/>
<input type="text" class="aa required standard" placeholder="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as they both share the same class, why not just target that class and propagate changes to other fields of that class:

```js
$(".aa").on("change",function() { $(".aa").val($(this).val()); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" class="aa required standard" placeholder="0"/>
<input type="text" class="aa required standard" placeholder="0"/>
```

You could even wrap that in a function so it can be used with other fields

```
function propagateChanges(cls){
    $(cls).on("change",function() { $(cls).val($(this).val()); });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, adding classes was just considered when asking the question, but it was again a little lengthy... but I could just set the variable and use the function as you have just mentioned. That will do the job nicely!